# How to implement Exactly-Once Kafka Consumer without manually assigning partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was going through [this article](https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/exactly-once-processing/) which explains how to ensure message is processed exactly once by doing following:

- Read (topic, partition, offset) from database on start/restart
- Read message from specific (topic, partition, offset)
- Atomically do following things:

  - Processing message
  - Commit offset to database as (topic, partition, offset)

As you can see, it explicitly specified from which partition to read messages. I feel its not good idea as it does not let allow Kafka to assign fair share of partition to active consumers. I am not able to come with logic to implement similar functionality without explicitly specifying partitions while polling kafka topic inside consumer. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good analysis.  You have a very good point and if possible you should certainly let kafka handle the partition assignment to consumers.

There is an alternative to consumer.Assign(Partition[]).  The kafka brokers will notify your consumers when a partition is revoked or assigned to the consumer.  For example, the dotnet client library has a 'SetPartitionsRevoked' and 'SetPartitionsAssigned' handler, that consumers can use to manage their offsets.

When a partition is revoked, persist your last processed offset for each partition being revoked to the database. When a new partition is assigned, get the last processed offset for that partition from the database and use that.

**C# Example:**

```
public class Program
{
   public void Main(string[] args)
   {

      using (
         var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(config)
                      .SetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler)
                      .SetPartitionsRevokedHandler(HandlePartitionsRevoked)
                      .SetPartitionsAssigned(HandlePartitionsAssigned)
                      .Build()
      )
      {
         while (true)
         {
            consumer.Consume()//.Poll()
         }
      }
   }

   public IEnumerable<TopicPartitionOffset> 
   HandlePartitionsRevoked
   (
      IConsumer<string, string> consumer, 
      List<TopicPartitionOffset> currentTopicPartitionOffsets
   )
   {
      Persist(<last processed offset for each partition in 
      'currentTopicPartitionOffsets'>);
      return tpos;
   }

   public IEnumerable<TopicPartitionOffset> HandlePartitionsAssigned
   (
      IConsumer<string, string> consumer, 
      List<TopicPartition> tps
    )
   {
      List<TopicPartitionOffset> tpos = FetchOffsetsFromDbForTopicPartitions(tps);
      return tpos
   }
}
```

**Java Example from the [ConsumerRebalanceListener Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):**

If writing in Java, there is a 'ConsumerRebalanceListener' interface that you can implement.  You then pass your implementation of the interface into the consumer.Subscribe(topic, listener) method. The example below is taken verbatim from the kafka docs linked above:

```
public class SaveOffsetsOnRebalance implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
       private Consumer<?,?> consumer;

       public SaveOffsetsOnRebalance(Consumer<?,?> consumer) {
           this.consumer = consumer;
       }

       public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
           // save the offsets in an external store using some custom code not described here
           for(TopicPartition partition: partitions)
              saveOffsetInExternalStore(consumer.position(partition));
       }

       public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
           // read the offsets from an external store using some custom code not described here
           for(TopicPartition partition: partitions)
              consumer.seek(partition, readOffsetFromExternalStore(partition));
    }
}
```

If my understanding is correct, you would call the java version like this: `consumer.Subscribe("My topic", new SaveOffsetsOnRebalance(consumer))`.

For more information, see the 'Storing Offsets Outside Kafka' section of the [kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

Here's an excerpt from those docs that summarizes how to store the partitions and offsets for exactly-once processing:

> Each record comes with its own offset, so to manage your own offset
>   you just need to do the following:
>
> - Configure enable.auto.commit=false
> - Use the offset provided with each ConsumerRecord to save your position.
> - On restart restore the position of the consumer using seek(TopicPartition, long).
>
> This type of usage is simplest when the partition assignment is also
>   done manually (this would be likely in the search index use case
>   described above). If the partition assignment is done automatically
>   special care is needed to handle the case where partition assignments
>   change. This can be done by providing a ConsumerRebalanceListener
>   instance in the call to subscribe(Collection,
>   ConsumerRebalanceListener) and subscribe(Pattern,
>   ConsumerRebalanceListener). For example, when partitions are taken
>   from a consumer the consumer will want to commit its offset for those
>   partitions by implementing
>   ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsRevoked(Collection). When
>   partitions are assigned to a consumer, the consumer will want to look
>   up the offset for those new partitions and correctly initialize the
>   consumer to that position by implementing
>   ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(Collection).
>
> Another common use for ConsumerRebalanceListener is to flush any
>   caches the application maintains for partitions that are moved
>   elsewhere.

Comment: That sounds really good. Now I need to find equivalent in Java API. There is no `ConsumerBuilder` in java API. Also I never came across anything which talks something related. I guess I should be looking at [assignment()](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html). But when should I call it? after calling subscribe(), I guess? Again it does not seem to be "re"-partitioning "handler" which gets called "automatically" when new partition is assigned. So it is not exactly what we want, right? [continued...]

Comment: [...continued] Also how will it work? if c1 has consumed till p1.30. c2 till p2.20. If I keep last consumed (topic,partition,offset) for each consumer separately, then c1 will consume p2.0, whereas p2 will consume p1.0, right? I need to share (topic,partition,offset) among consumers so that a new consumer will start consuming newly assigned partition from where other consumer left consuming, right? (That is c1 from p2.21 and c2 from p1.31).

Comment: I added some information for the java implementation, as well as some useful documentation.

The '.assignment()' will just return the topics and partitions currently assigned to your consumer.  It looks like you'll use an overload of the .subscribe that lets your provide a rebalance handler.

The answer to your second question is where the 'OnPartitionsRevoked' method comes in.  In that method you save the current offset for your consumers' positions.  Then, in the 'OnPartitionsAssigned' method, you retrieve those offsets from the database for the assigned partitions.

Comment: Very sorry for no reply for long time...I feel we dont need to have anything in `onPartitionsRevoked()`, as we update offset and log processing output together in the same database transaction when we have successfully consumed and processed the message (so that message consuming and processing is atomic, no message is processed multiple times or left unprocessed). Right?

Comment: You would not need to provide 'onParitionsRevoked()' if you finish processing each message before taking the next message from the topic.  

However, if you batch messages in memory before processing them, then you'll need to provide a OnPartitionsRevoked handler that either removes those messages from memory or processes them.

Comment: Small related doubt. That article sets `enable.auto.commit` to `false`. The example stores offset to external database. However I was guessing what harm it will do if we keep `enable.auto.commit` to `true`?

Comment: As soon as you retrieve a message from the topic it will be committed, so if you fail to completely process the message (for example, you lose db-connectivity or your app dies), that message will be lost and never processed. Comments aren't meant for extended conversations, so I encourage you to either create additional questions, or reach out via e-mail.

Comment: this is in which scenario? With `enable.auto.commit=true`, I guess messages are committed after interval equal to `offset.flush.timeout.ms`. So if n messages are consumed in this interval, all n will be committed. Also, I am saving offset to external database when they are fully processed, so I was guessing when offset committed to kafka will be used. If consumer fail while processing message, it will fetch the last fully processed message offset + 1 from the external database and will correctly consume from next message. Right?